# Sqlite select a record inserted or updated in last 5 minutes

Tags: sqlite, date, datetime, select

I am trying to select any record that has been inserted or updated for the last five minutes in a sqlite3 data table where the date column `updated_at` is in format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`:

```
               CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp_tb(
                    emp_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                    emp_names TEXT NOT NULL,
                    emp_number TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                    ent_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    active INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT "0",
                    updated_at TEXT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now', 'localtime')),
                    syncstatus INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT "0")
```

I have tried the following, but it returns either any record for the current day not necessarily updated in last 5 minutes or none at all:

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_names FROM emp_tb WHERE ent_id = ? \
      AND date(updated_at) = date('now') AND time(updated_at) >= time('now','-5 minutes')
```

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_names FROM emp_tb WHERE ent_id = ? \
      AND datetime(updated_at) >= datetime('now','-5 minutes')
```

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_names FROM emp_tb WHERE ent_id = ? \
    AND updated_at >= datetime('now','-5 minutes')
```

I know how to do it in Mysql but how do you query time for a record updated or inserted in the last five minutes in Sqlite3?

Comment: Actually your last 2 queries should be working.  What happens when you run them?

Comment: They return a record but the record's time is more than 5 five minutes old.  The day is just the same.

Comment: Well can you include sample input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column `updated_at` has the proper format, so there is no need to use the function `datetime()` for its values.

Your last query should work, but maybe there is a timezone problem, so use also `'localtime'`:

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_names 
FROM emp_tb 
WHERE ent_id = ? 
AND updated_at >= datetime('now', '-5 minutes', 'localtime')
```

Comment: You are correct, `localtime` parameter solved it.  Thanks!.